# #1251 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Despues de haber instalado mysqlserver 5.7.22 en un servidor con Centos 6.9 y php 5.4 e instalar phpmyadmin cuando intento ingresar en phpMyAdmin recibo este error a pesar de poder utilizar este usuario para ingresar a mysql y haber configurado dicho usario en /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.

```html
#1251 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

Luego de este error no puedo avanzar, todo este problema comenzó luego de actualizar mysql de la version 5.1 a la 5.5 aquí comenzó el problema, luego se actualizó a la ultima version estable la 5.7.22 y el problema persiste.

Cualquier ayuda que puedan brindar sería de mucha utilidad.

Comment: te dejo este enlace de la documentación oficial de mysql mencionando este error https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-client.html

Comment: Por ahi lei que tratando de conectar a traves de la opcion insecureAuth se puede resolver el problema pero ni idea como se hace eso :(